# i am using latest version of matplotlib and getting error with axis? how to fix this

Tags: python, image, plot, syntax-error, figure

i am using latest version of matplotlib which is 3.7
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
i am getting this error
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'axes'. Did you mean: 'axis'?

i tried latest version 3.7 but issue not resolved

Comment: Please add the necessary details and formatting. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something other than Jupyter Notebook:

1. The first way is to use this at the end of your code to save the graph in photo format: plt.savefig("my_plot.png")
2. If it is not resolved, you must first install OpenGL on your system so that there is a graph display environment in your system.
   In Linux: sudo apt install opengl